# XSLT: Alternative to Sequential Ifs to Achieve Specific Order

Tags: xml, xslt

**XML:**

```
<root>
  <item>
    <key>mustBeSECONDKey</key>
    <value>MustBeSECONDValue</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <key>mustBeFIRSTKey</key>
    <value>MustBeFIRSTValue</value>
  </item>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <file>
      <xsl:for-each select="root/item">
        <xsl:if test="key[text()='mustBeFIRSTKey']">
          <xsl:element name="someCustomTagName">
            <xsl:value-of select="value" />
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="root/item">
        <xsl:if test="key[text()='mustBeSECONDKey']">
          <xsl:element name="anotherNameOfATag">
            <xsl:value-of select="value" />
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </file>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<file>
  <someCustomTagName>MustBeFIRSTValue</someCustomTagName>
  <anotherNameOfATag>MustBeSECONDValue</anotherNameOfATag>
</file>
```

The idea here is that I want to make sure that the tags end up in the output document in an order that I specify. So I'm doing that by basically saying "look through everything and find the first thing, then look through everything and find the second thing." This obviously works.

However - and this would be the crux of this question - I imagine that there must be a more efficient way to accomplish this goal (possibly more than one way). What is it?

And there's a further wrinkle. Suppose that `mustBeFIRSTKey` has two possible values, `MustBeFIRSTValueUno` and `MustBeFIRSTValueNi`. I then want to map these two values to another set of two values, `Gazpacho` and `Sushi`, respectively. So

```
<item>
  <key>mustBeFIRSTKey</key>
  <value>MustBeFIRSTValueNi</value>
</item>
```

becomes

```
<mustBeFIRSTKey>Sushi</mustBeFIRSTKey>
```

**Edit:** I've discovered my problem was mostly a conceptual one looking at the Java side of things. During the setup of my `Transformer` I was doing this:

```
StreamSource xsltSource = new StreamSource(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(transformLocation));
```

I should have been doing this:

```
StreamSource xsltSource = new StreamSource(ClassLoader.getSystemResource(transformLocation).toString());
```

That `StreamSource` constructor sets the `systemId`, which allows me to use @Ian_Robert's more clever solution from below, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <!-- I discovered I could merge the $map and $inlineMap variables. -->
  <xsl:variable name="inlineMap" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name = 'inlineMap']/map">
    <map>
      <key from="mustBeFIRSTKey" to="someCustomTagName" />
      <key from="mustBeSECONDKey" to="anotherNameOfATag">
        <value from="MustBeSECONDValueUno" to="Gazpacho" />
        <value from="MustBeSECONDValueNi" to="Sushi" />
      </key>
    </map>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:key name="valueMap" match="value" use="concat(../@from, '|', @from)" />
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:variable name="items" select="item" />
    <file>
      <xsl:for-each select="$inlineMap">
        <xsl:for-each select="key">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$items[key = current()/@from]">
            <xsl:with-param name="elementName" select="@to"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </file>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:param name="elementName" />
    <xsl:variable name="currentItem" select="." />
    <xsl:element name="{$elementName}">
      <xsl:for-each select="$inlineMap">
        <xsl:variable name="value" select="key('valueMap', concat($currentItem/key, '|', $currentItem/value))" />
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$value">
            <xsl:value-of select="$value/@to" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$currentItem/value" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This example strips away the logic for handling values without mappings, because for my problem, there are none.

Comment: There are one motive to not use only one loop with `<xsl:if test="key[text()='MustBeFIRSTKey' or text()='MustBeSECONDKey']">`? ... Then you can use [xsl:sort](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a trick you can use with `<xsl:sort>` to achieve this

```
<xsl:variable name="sortOrder" select="'|MustBeFIRSTKey|MustBeSECONDKey|--' />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <file>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/item">
      <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-after($sortOrder,
                                                      concat('|', key, '|')))"
                data-type="number"
                order="descending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </file>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:element name="{key}">
    <xsl:value-of select="value" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This will put MustBeFIRSTKey first, MustBeSECONDKey second, and any other key values after this in their original order.  It works by producing a numeric sorting value for each key based on its position in the `sortOrder` variable.  For MustBeFIRSTKey the value will be `string-length('MustBeSECONDKey|--')` (18), for MustBeSECONDKey it will be `string-length('--')` (2) and for anything else it will be `string-length('')` (0).

To change the tag names you can extend this approach to use the variable to encode the mapping too:

```
<xsl:variable name="sortOrder" select="concat(
          '|MustBeFIRSTKey+someCustomTagName',
          '|MustBeSECONDKey+anotherNameOfATag',
          '|--' />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <file>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root/item">
      <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-after($sortOrder,
                                                      concat('|', key, '+')))"
                data-type="number"
                order="descending" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </file>
</xsl:template>

<!-- for keys that have a mapping -->
<xsl:template match="item[substring-after($sortOrder, concat('|', key, '+'))]">
  <xsl:element name="{substring-before(
       substring-after($sortOrder, concat('|', key, '+')), '|')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="value" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- for keys that don't -->
<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:element name="{key}">
    <xsl:value-of select="value" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Edit: for your third question, if you want to remap the values as well as the keys then I think a separate mapping file is probably going to be the clearest approach.

**mapping.xml**

```
<map>
  <key from="MustBeFIRSTKey" to="someCustomTagName">
    <value from="MustBeFIRSTValueUno" to="Gazpacho" />
    <value from="MustBeFIRSTValueNi" to="Sushi" />
  </key>
  <key from="MustBeSECONDKey" to="anotherNameOfATag" />
</map>
```

**stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:variable name="map" select="document('mapping.xml')/map" />

  <!-- define some keys used for looking up entries in the mapping -->
  <xsl:key name="keyMap" match="key" use="@from" />
  <xsl:key name="valMap" match="value" use="concat(../@from, '|', @from)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="items" select="root/item" />
    <file>
      <!-- the key function looks up nodes in the "current document", so
           we need this for-each to switch the context to the mapping file
           for the key lookups -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$map">
        <!-- go through the keys in order -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key">
          <!-- process all items with that key... -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$items[key = current()/@from]">
            <!-- ... using the mapped tag name -->
            <xsl:with-param name="tagName" select="@to"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- now process any remaining keys that don't have a mapping -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$items[not(key('keyMap', key))]" />
      </xsl:for-each>
    </file>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <!-- tag name defaults to the key text if another name is not passed in -->
    <xsl:param name="tagName" select="key" />
    <xsl:variable name="curItem" select="." />
    <xsl:element name="{$tagName}">
      <!-- again, switch focus to the mapping file for key lookups -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$map">
        <!-- do we have a remapping for the item's *value*? -->
        <xsl:variable name="value"
            select="key('valMap', concat($curItem/key, '|', $curItem/value))" />
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$value"><xsl:value-of select="$value/@to" /></xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$curItem/value" /></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If the mapping file is small enough you could include it inline in the stylesheet by replacing

```
  <xsl:variable name="map" select="document('mapping.xml')/map" />
```

with

```
  <xsl:variable name="inlineMap">
    <map>
      <key from="..." to="..."/>
      <!-- ... -->
    </map>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="map"
                select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='inlineMap']/map" />
```

This uses the trick that `document('')` gives you access to the XML tree of the stylesheet itself.

Finally, note that the `keyMap` is only used to find items whose keys *don't* have an entry in the mapping file.  If you have mappings for all possible keys you can leave this key out (and the `<xsl:apply-templates select="$items[not(key('keyMap', key))]" />` which uses it).

Comment: The `inlineMap` thing doesn't seem to be working. I think it's the `document('')` that's failing. I did an `<xsl:copy-of select="$inlineMap" />` and it printed out `inlineMap`. I did the same with `map` and got nothing. I did the same with `document('')` and got nothing. I happen to be using standard JAXP in Java, so perhaps it's a problem with this implementation?

Comment: @RandomHuman it depends on how you're loading the stylesheet.  In order for `document('')` to work the processor needs to know the location from which the stylesheet was loaded.  If you're loading it from a `StreamSource` that you created from an `InputStream` or `Reader` and didn't specify the `systemId` then it won't work, you need to use `new StreamSource(new File("...."))` or one of the two-parameter constructors instead.

Comment: @RandomHuman but if you're working in Java and creating the XSLT processor programatically then you could switch to [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml) which would give you access to XSLT 2.0 and then you don't need any tricks, you can just use `$inlineMap` directly.

Comment: After fighting with it for awhile, I've found that I have no way to get the value in order to set the `systemId`. I'm using `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(transformLocation)`, which gives me an `InputStream`, and there is no way to get at the path from there. I tried doing `<xsl:variable name="map" select="document('mapping.xsl')/map" />`, but that seems to use relative path and it can never find the referenced document.

Comment: @RandomHuman `ClassLoader.getSystemResource(transformLocation).toString()` will do the job. Or you could try the exslt `node-set` function, which is supported by Xalan (the default javax.xml.transform processor).

Comment: @Ian_Roberts `ClassLoader.getSystemResource(transformLocation).toString()` worked, but I think I prefer the `node-set` solution more, as it keeps it all confined inside the XSLT. I did `<xsl:variable name="map" select="exsl:node-set($inlineMap)/map" />` to get it working on the `inlineMap`, but I can't seem to figure out what to modify in the `valMap` to get it to start working again (MustBeSECONDValueNi -> Sushi).

Comment: @RandomHuman you shouldn't need to modify anything, just insert the content that was in mapping.xml into the `inlineMap` variable declaration and it should work the same.

Comment: @Ian_Roberts It seems as though the `xsl:when` test on the `value` variable in the `item` template is always returning `false`.

Comment: @RandomHuman all I can say is I've tested it here and it works for me on both Xalan and xsltproc (once I fix up your example so the various names match up - your XML in the question uses a mixture of `mustBeFIRST` in some places and `MustBeFIRST` in others).

Comment: @Ian_Roberts I think it's the `valMap` key that is broken. I keep trying to select things from it and there's nothing in there. I think it's confused and takes "`match="value"`" to mean that it needs to find `<value>` nodes in the XML document the XSLT is being applied to, and not the XSLT itself. I'm not sure why setting the `systemId` allows this to work, but using `exsl:node-set()` instead causes this to cease functioning.

Comment: Yeah, I just put some `<value>` nodes in my XML document, and `valMap` now contains them. So the question would be: How do I make a `<xsl:key>` that points at the XSLT itself instead of the XML document to which it's being applied?

Comment: @RandomHuman as I explained in the comment to the for-each, the `key` function is supposed to pick nodes out of the document that contains the current context node (which should be the document fragment in `$map`, at this point).  Again, it works for me, there must be something different in your real setup compared to the sample in the question.

Comment: @Ian_Roberts Then I guess doing `<xsl:variable name="map" select="exsl:node-set($inlineMap)/map" />` does not change the context to the XSLT like doing `<xsl:variable name="map" select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name = 'inlineMap']/map" />` does. Which means I cannot use it.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by writing a template

```
<xsl:template match="item">
          <xsl:element name="{key}">
            <xsl:value-of select="value" />
          </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Now you can use

```
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <file>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item[key ='MustBeFIRSTKey']"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item[key = 'MustBeSECONDKey']"/>
    </file>
  </xsl:template>
```

With XSLT 2.0 you would only need

```
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <file>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="item[key ='MustBeFIRSTKey'], item[key = 'MustBeSECONDKey']"/>
    </file>
  </xsl:template>
```

And of course with both XSLT 1.0 as well as 2.0 you could define a key

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="item" use="key"/>
```

and then shorten the code to

```
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <file>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', 'MustBeFIRSTKey')"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', 'MustBeSECONDKey')"/>
    </file>
  </xsl:template>
```

respectively

```
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <file>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('k1', 'MustBeFIRSTKey'), key('k1', 'MustBeSECONDKey')"/>
    </file>
  </xsl:template>
```

Of course depending on your intended sorting you could use `xsl:sort` instead of spelling out the order.

Comment: "...you could define a key..." I have no context for this statement, and I don't know what's happening in the subsequent example ("key('k1',..." What the hell is k1?). I feel like you skipped one or more steps you thought should be "obvious" to everyone that clearly aren't.

Comment: Sorry, the code for defining the key was in the answer but I forgot to mark it up correctly as code so it was hidden when you read the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would make this data-driven. Define the order of items in a separate piece of XML, either a separate document or part of the stylesheet:

```
<order>
  <item>mustbefirst</item>
  <item>mustbesecond</item>
</order>
```

and use this to drive the stylesheet processing:

```
<xsl:template match="order">
  <xsl:for-each select="item">
    <xsl:variable name="target" select="$root/item[key=current()]">
    <xsl:if test="$target">
      <xsl:element name="$target/key"><xsl:value-of select="$target/value"/></xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

where $root is bound to your "root" element.